# Unwanted page break

Tags: page-breaking

My code generated unwanted page break once I start the `align` environment. The best way to show it, is to provide the relevant code so someone can compile it.

My code looks like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\section{Derivations}
\subsection{Derivations2}
bla bla 
\begin{equation}
c^i_1 + \frac{c^i_2}{1+r} + (n-r)\frac{x^i}{1+r}  = wl^i  -\tau 
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
& d(c^i_1) + d(\frac{c^i_2}{1+r}) + d((n-r)\frac{x^i}{1+r})   = d(wl^i)  -d(\tau) \\
& d(c^i_1) + \big[c^i_2 d(\frac{1}{1+r}) +  \frac{1}{1+r} dc^i_2 \big] + \big[x^i d(\frac{n-r}{1+r}) +  \frac{n-r}{1+r} dx^i \big]= d(wl^i)  -d(\tau) \\
& d(c^i_1) +  \frac{1}{1+r} dc^i_2 + \frac{n-r}{1+r} dx^i  =  d(wl^i)  -d(\tau) - c^i_2 d(\frac{1}{1+r}) - x^i d(\frac{n-r}{1+r}) \\
& d(c^i_1) +  \frac{1}{1+r} dc^i_2 + \frac{n-r}{1+r} dx^i  =  d(wl^i)  -d(\tau) - c^i_2 d(\frac{1}{1+r}) - x^i (n-r)d(\frac{1}{1+r}) - \frac{x^i}{1+r}d(n-r) \\
& d(c^i_1) +  \frac{1}{1+r} dc^i_2 + \frac{n-r}{1+r} dx^i  =  d(wl^i)  -d(\tau) - c^i_2 d(\frac{1}{1+r}) - x^i (n-r)d(\frac{1}{1+r}) + \frac{x^i}{1+r}dr \\
& d(c^i_1) +  \frac{1}{1+r} dc^i_2 + \frac{n-r}{1+r} dx^i =   d(wl^i)  -d(\tau) - \left[c^i_2 +  x^i (n-r) \right]d(\frac{1}{1+r}) + \frac{x^i}{1+r}dr \\
& d(c^i_1) +  \frac{1}{1+r} dc^i_2 + \frac{n-r}{1+r} dx^i =   d(wl^i)  -d(\tau)  + \frac{\left[c^i_2 +  x^i (n-r) \right]}{(1+r)^2}d(r) + \frac{x^i}{1+r}dr \\
& d(c^i_1) +  \frac{1}{1+r} dc^i_2 + \frac{n-r}{1+r} dx^i =   d(wl^i)  -d(\tau)  + \bigg( \frac{1}{1+r}\bigg)\frac{\left[c^i_2 +  x^i (n-r) \right]}{(1+r)}dr + \frac{x^i}{1+r}dr \\
& d(c^i_1) +  \frac{1}{1+r} dc^i_2 + \frac{n-r}{1+r} dx^i =   d(wl^i)  -d(\tau)  + \bigg( \frac{1}{1+r}\bigg)(wl^i  -\tau  - c^i_1)d(r) + \frac{x^i}{1+r}dr \\
& d(c^i_1) +  \frac{1}{1+r} dc^i_2 + \frac{n-r}{1+r} dx^i =   d(wl^i)  -d(\tau)  + \bigg( \frac{1}{1+r}\bigg)(\underbrace{wl^i + x^i -\tau  - c^i_1}_{s^i})dr  \\
& d(c^i_1) +  \frac{1}{1+r} dc^i_2 + \frac{n-r}{1+r} dx^i =   d(wl^i)  -d(\tau)  + \bigg( \frac{s^i}{1+r}\bigg) dr \\
& d(c^i_1) +  \frac{1}{1+r} dc^i_2 + \frac{n-r}{1+r} dx^i =   d(wl^i)  -d(\tau)  + \bigg( \frac{s^i}{1+r}\bigg) dr +  \bigg( \frac{S}{1+r}\bigg)dr -  \bigg( \frac{S}{1+r}\bigg)dr \\
 & = d(wl^i) - d(\tau)  +  \bigg( \frac{S}{1+r}\bigg)dr +  \bigg( \frac{s^ i - S}{1+r}\bigg)dr \\
 & = d(wl^i) - d[(r-n)b]  +  \bigg( \frac{S}{1+r}\bigg)dr +  \bigg( \frac{s^ i - S}{1+r}\bigg)dr \\
 & = d(wl^i) - d[(r-n)b]  +  \bigg( \frac{S}{1+r}\bigg)dr +  \bigg( \frac{s^ i - S}{1+r}\bigg)dr \\
 & = l^i dw - \left[(r-n)db + bdr \right] +  \bigg( \frac{S}{1+r}\bigg)dr +  \bigg( \frac{s^ i - S}{1+r}\bigg)dr \\
 & = l^i (-k) dr - \left[(r-n)db + bdr \right] +  \bigg( \frac{S}{1+r}\bigg)dr +  \bigg( \frac{s^ i - S}{1+r}\bigg)dr \\
 & =  - l^i k dr - (r-n)db - bdr - kdr + kdr +  \bigg( \frac{S}{1+r}\bigg)dr +  \bigg( \frac{s^ i - S}{1+r}\bigg)dr \\
 & = k (1-l^i)dr  - (k+b)dr - (r-n)db +  \bigg( \frac{S}{1+r}\bigg)dr +  \big( \frac{s^ i - S}{1+r}\big)dr \\
 & = - (k+b)dr - (r-n)db +  \bigg( \frac{S}{1+r}\bigg)dr + \bigg[\big( \frac{s^ i - S}{1+r}\big) + k(1-l^i)\bigg] dr \\
 & = - \bigg[(k+b) - \big(\frac{S}{1+r}\big) \bigg]dr - (r-n)db + \bigg[\big( \frac{s^ i - S}{1+r}\big) + k(1-l^i)\bigg] dr  \label{total change in life-cycle budget in general}\\
 & = - \bigg[(k+b) - \big(\frac{(1+n)(k+b)}{1+r}\big) \bigg]dr - (r-n)db + \bigg[\big( \frac{s^ i - S}{1+r}\big) + k(1-l^i)\bigg] dr \\
 & = - \bigg[k + b -  \frac{(1+n)k}{1+r} - \frac{(1+n)b}{1+r}\bigg]dr - (r-n)db + \bigg[\big( \frac{s^ i - S}{1+r}\big) + k(1-l^i)\bigg] dr \\
 & = - \bigg[\left(k -  \frac{(1+n)k}{1+r}\right) + \left( b- \frac{(1+n)b}{1+r}\right)\bigg]dr - (r-n)db + \bigg[\big( \frac{s^ i - S}{1+r}\big) + k(1-l^i)\bigg] dr \\
 & = - \frac{r-n}{1+r} (k+b) dr - (r-n)db + \bigg[\big( \frac{s^ i - S}{1+r}\big) + k(1-l^i)\bigg] dr \label{total effect in the life-cycle budget}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I understand that LaTeX, since I have the `align` environment, tries to fit it in one page, but this leaves the other page almost empty. Is there a way to fix it? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: See `\allowdisplaybreaks` and `\displaybreak` in the amsmath documentation amsldoc. You can also enlarge the page with `\enlargethispage`.

Comment: ... or you could `\end{align}` and `\begin{align}` again where the break is wanted.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer please, could you write the answer?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `\allowdisplaybreaks` and `\displaybreak` in the `amsmath` documentation `amsldoc`. You can also enlarge the page with `\enlargethispage`.